# Linkar estilos corretamente

Tags: html5

Estou aos poucos me aprofundando no mundo web, e hoje percebi algo incomum no meu código, bom, incomum **mais ou menos** vamos aos exemplos.

Neste código eu utilizo o **type="text/css"**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="caminho aqui">
```

E neste eu já não utilizo mais

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="caminho aqui">
```

Ambos funcionam, mas há algum problema se não definir o type?
Preciso de uma resposta bem concreta que sane minha dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje em dia já não é necessário usar o atributo `type`.

Na [versão 4 do HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#adef-type-A) ainda era referido o atributo, mas indicando que ele "dá uma sugestão" ao browser sobre o conteúdo, e pelo texto depreende-se que não era obrigatório:

> This attribute gives an advisory hint as to the content type of the content available at the link target address. [...] Authors who use this attribute...

Na [especificação do HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#adef-type-A) ainda é mais claro:

> The type attribute gives the MIME type of the linked resource. It is purely advisory.

*O atributo é puramente uma sugestão* (traduzindo livremente).

Comment: Já que não obtive mais respostas, estarei marcando a sua como resolvido, e obrigado.